# Swift: multiple initialisers with common initialisation part

Tags: swift

I have a `class Node`

```
class Node {
  let name:String
  let device: MTLDevice
  let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer

  init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: Array<Float>){
    self.name=name
    self.device=device
    self.vertexBuffer=toVertexBuffer(vertices)
  }
  init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, count: Int){
    self.name=name
    self.device=device
    self.vertexBuffer=toVertexBuffer(vertices, count)
  }
}
```

I want to normalise my class initialisation. I want to move initialisation of `name` and `device` members into separate function or initialiser to avoid code redundancy. Some thing like

```
class Node {
  let name:String
  let device: MTLDevice
  let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer

  init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: Array<Float>){
    self.init(name:name, device:device)
    self.vertexBuffer=toVertexBuffer(vertices)
  }
  init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, count: Int){
    self.init(name:name, device:device)
    self.vertexBuffer=toVertexBuffer(vertices, count)
  }
  private init(name: String, device: MTLDevice){
    self.name=name
    self.device=device
  }
}
```

I get some error with the above code as you know. How to do it right way?

Comment: Whats the error ?

Comment: @priyal I didn't try but apparently it is wrong. I said `I get some error` not `I got some error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. Create a designated initializer that is private (if you do not want it to be called directly) and add convenience initializers for the values that need converting (see [Designated Initializers and Convenience Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203))

```
class Node {
    let name: String
    let device: MTLDevice
    let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer

    private init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, buffer: MTLBuffer) {
        self.name = name
        self.device = device
        self.vertexBuffer = buffer
    }

    convenience init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: Array<Float>) {
        self.init(name: name, device: device, buffer: toVertexBuffer(vertices))
    }

    convenience init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, count: Int) {
        self.init(name: name, device: device, buffer: toVertexBuffer(vertices, count))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be work. You need a designated initializer, then other initializer just call this.

```
class Node {
let name: String
let device: MTLDevice
let vertexBuffer: MTLBuffer


init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>, count: Int){
    self.name = name
    self.device = device
    self.vertexBuffer = MTLBuffer()
}
convenience init(name: String, device: MTLDevice, vertices: UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>){
    self.init(name: name, device: device, vertices: vertices, count: 0)
}
```

}